# Using IN statement in parameterized crosstab query in Access

Tags: ms-access, parameters, crosstab

I have a crosstab query which queries a bunch of locations and gets their measurement readings. I pivot on the measurement readings so I get a table which has all the measurements for a location/date combo on each line. This works fine for getting all the data. It also works fine for filtering on one value per field. i.e. `WHERE LocationID = ? AND MeasureID = ?` but what I really need is to have something like `WHERE LocationID IN (?) AND MeasureID IN (?)` where ? is an array (or whatever gets to job done. Is this possible?

On my forms I'm using a DAO.QueryDef object to build my recordsets. I'd like to avoid building the entire query string in VBA if possible, mostly because this particular query is pretty long and I'd rather it live in a view and not a code module. With that said I *can* build it all in VBA but it's just not the desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use replace.

```
sSQL = "SELECT lots of sql WHERE LocationID IN (qqlocidqq)"
sSQLWithLoc = Replace (sSQL, "qqlocidqq", "1,2,3,4")

Dim qdf As QueryDef

'A query that exists
Set qdf= CurrentDB.QueryDefs("MyJunkQuery")
'Permanently change the sql of that query
qdf.SQL = sSQLWithLoc
```

Looking into this a little further, it may suit you to use Instr, like so:

```
SELECT Table1.LocationID
FROM Table1
WHERE InStr([@List],[LocationID])>0
```

Tested like so:

```
PARAMETERS Number_List Text(50);
TRANSFORM Count(Table1.AKey) AS CountOfAKey
SELECT Table1.AText
FROM Table1
WHERE InStr([Number_List],[ANumber])>0
GROUP BY Table1.AText
PIVOT Table1.ANumber;
```

Where Table1 consists of fields AKey, AText, and ANumber. Number_List is a comma separated list of numbers supplied by a parameter. Instr checks for the existence of ANumber from Table1 in the supplied parameter.

There is a problem with overlap 1,2,12, but a creative use of commas may suit:

```
WHERE InStr("," & [Number_List] & "," , "," & [ANumber] & ",")>0
```

Of course the delimiter does not have to be a comma, | is often useful.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. you can use it with a recordset or set the sql of a query or set the record source of a form.

Comment: I am able to do this already but it's what I'm trying to avoid. I'd rather not build the SQL like this in VBA. What I'd like to do is define my query in a `Query` and pass only the parameters.

Comment: So foreaxample in another part of my program I have this `Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("SavedQuery")` then I can `qdef.parameters("Parameter1") = "SomeValue"` and I don't have to write any SQL in my UI side of things.

Comment: No, I do not believe you can have a list as a parameter. This is building the sql from an existing string in VBA, however, you can take a string from an existing query and add " AND locationid IN ("

Comment: What makes a simple addendum of `AND LocationID IN(...)` tough is that because it is a crosstab query the WHERE clause needs to be nested between `Group BY` and `FROM`. hmmm but maybe that action is not so difficult...

Comment: I have added another possibility

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14288/discussion-between-remou-and-brad)